# String overflow in C++

Tags: c++

I'm converting large graph files using a simple C++ program. Basically I mainly want to switch the delimiters used in the file. These graph files contain extremely long lines. My converting works fine for small files, but I lose edges in the output file for the large files. So I checked what the part of my code that reads actually returns and it seems the error is already in there. Using the following, I do not receive the full lines from the graph in `curLineMetis` or `ssMetis` (My guess is that there's an overflow somewhere and I lose the last part of the line thats too big for the allocated memory)

```
using namespace std;
void exampleFunc(const char* inputfileMetis) {
    ifstream metisFile;
    metisFile.open(inputfileMetis, ios::in);
    if(!metisFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open input file";
        return;
    }
    long nMet = 0;
    long mMet = 0;
    string curLineMetis;
    // skip first line
    getline(metisFile, curLineMetis);
    while(getline(metisFile, curLineMetis)) {
        nMet++;
        long targetMetis;
        stringstream ssMetis(curLineMetis);
        while(ssMetis >> targetMetis) {
            mMet++;
        }
   }
}
```

I checked on google and it said std::string managed its own memory and would not overflow? I also tried it without the stringstream, just using an iterator over chars from the string before and the same happened. I'm using c++11 if that makes a difference. (the error expresses itself e.g. in `mMet` being different from the number of edges stated in the graph file itself, while the number of vertices `nMet` is the same, and the number of edges is also correct for smaller graphs)

Comment: If you're just substituting delimiters, why not `sed` or even `tr`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps one of your lines has something non-integral in it somewhere?

Comment: I'm adding the line number as well at the beginning of each line and the delimiters vary at certain points, so it was easier for me to just write a small program. Also, I'm not very familiar with all these unix tools, so I might overlook some simple solution.

Comment: was thinking sed too

Comment: Barry, calling the above code on e.g. the uk-2002 graph from [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/dimacs10/archive/clustering.shtml) will cause `mMet` to be 523113442 instead of 2*261787258 = 523574516 as it should be. The graph files this happens on are all >100MB, however.

If you need code for all, add a main function 
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        exampleFunc(argv[0]);
    }
and add a 
    cout << mMet;
at the end of exampleFunc

Comment: @Gaze Linking to a 100MB file does not a **minimal** or **complete** example make.

Comment: The in-2004 graph has the same problem and is only around 11MB. If I knew how to make a minimal graph example that produced this behavior, I'd probably have solved the problem already. (which is also why I did not link it in the first post)

Comment: targetMetis seems to be uninitialized, and is used too for byte shift!

Comment: @Gaze Cannot duplicate:  I took the time to download that 100 meg file, and created the following program:  http://ideone.com/U8TLnZ  The program runs successfully (completes in less than a minute using Visual Studio 2015, release).  An output file is created from reading all the lines from the input file.  Using a diff tool, the original input file and output file are exactly the same, with the only difference being an extra carriage return at the end.  So I don't see an issue with not reading an entire line, as you claim.  All lines are read correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and whats the value of mMet at the end? 523574516?

Comment: The value of mMet is 21,826,136. Where is the proof that mMet should be 523574516?  "*Using the following, I do not receive the full lines from the graph*" -- This is demonstrably false, given the code I linked to.  If the full lines were not received, why would the input file and output file be exactly the same?  Run the code yourself -- you have the file, and hopefully you have a file difference tool.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry for the delay and thanks for your efforts. The graph files store the number of vertices n and the number of edges m in the first line. After that, the i+1th line represents the vertex i and each entry represents an edge to the vertex with the id of the entry. ([for a small example check out e.g. the tiny_01.graph here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/metis_graph/metis_graph.html) ) The graphs are undirected, meaning if we count each edge entry, we get each edge twice so our m should be 2* the second number in the first line.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Also, I don't want to print out the whole string but rather do something for each edge (which gives me the loss of some edges with the usage of stringstream. The same construct (
    stringstream ss(curLineMetis) 
is used in a different tool written by someone else, that does not have my problem). If you want to check some things again and deleted the 100mb graph as I suspect, see my comment above for a 10mb graph that produces the same error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what is going wrong for you with your code. The standard library functions and types should be able to handle long lines. However, to reduce memory usage and to work around your problem you might want to process a part of a line at a time. Since the file format seemed interesting I wrote this program to read the graph into a `vector<vector<int>>`. It reproduces the graph file from that representation and produces a file identical to the input. Perhaps something in here will be of use to you. Good luck.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t const buf_size = 40; // big enough for a 64bit integer and then some
    char buf[buf_size]; 

    assert(argc >= 2);

    std::ifstream is (argv[1]);
    assert(is);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph;
    std::vector<int> line;

    std::string header;
    std::getline(is, header);
    { std::istringstream is_header (header);
    size_t n;
    is_header >> n;
    graph.reserve(n);
    }

    char delim;
    for (;;) {
        is.get(buf, buf_size, ' ');
        if (!is) break;
        is.get(delim);
        line.push_back(std::atoi(buf));
        while (is.peek() == '\n') {
            graph.emplace_back(std::move(line));
            (void) is.get();
        }
    }

    std::cout << graph.size() << '\n';
    size_t max_row = graph[0].size();
    size_t row_sum = graph[0].size();

    for (size_t i = 1, I = graph.size(); i < I; ++i) {
        max_row = std::max(max_row, graph[i].size());
        row_sum += graph[i].size();
    }
    std::cout << max_row << '\n';
    std::cout << row_sum << '\n';

    std::ofstream os ("dup.graph");
    os << header << '\n';
    for (size_t i = 0, I = graph.size(); i < I; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0, J = graph[i].size(); j < J; ++j)
            os << graph[i][j] << ' ';
        os << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```